# Generar módulos en Python y Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero crear una especie de módulo que acepte dos entradas que sean dos números, que se den por un bloque que sea constante y me devuelva la suma o que la guarde en memoria y la verdad es que no sé por dónde atacarlo. Lo he hecho con un canvas, pero entiendo que eso no es lo más eficiente o ni siquiera posible. ¿Cómo podría enfocarlo?

Dejo por aquí mi código y una imagen de lo que sale, por si ayuda.

```
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk() 
  
root.geometry('500x500') 

resultado=0

def suma(a,b):
    r=a+b
    return r
 
c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400) 
c.place(x=0, y=0) 
 
c.create_rectangle(150,150,300,300,fill="black")
c.create_oval(300,220,310,230,fill="red")
c.create_oval(140,190,150,200,fill="blue")
c.create_oval(140,250,150,260,fill="blue")

c.create_rectangle(70,70,130,130,fill='green')
c.create_oval(130,100,140,110,fill="blue")

c.create_rectangle(70,300,130,360,fill='green')
c.create_oval(130,330,140,340,fill="blue")

resultado=suma()

btn = Button(root, text='Suma',commnad=lambda:suma()) 
  
btn.place(x=200, y=400) 
print(resultado)
  
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, la verdad no es muy clara tu pregunta, ¿Cómo ingresas los valores a tu función? O ¿Cómo esperarías que funcionara? ¿Qué significa "que se den por un bloque que sea constante y me devuelva la suma o que la guarde en memoria"? Es decir, ¿Quieres 2 números que siempre sean constantes y los sume?

Comment: Veo que no me he explicado muy bien, lo que quiero hacer es parte de un código más grande y he sacado una parte con un ejemplo sencillo. A ver si consigo explicarme mejor. Me gustaría que los cuadrados verdes tuvieran ya un valor asignado de base y que dentro del cuadrado negro se realice la operación, en este caso la suma y lo guarde en la variable resultado. Es querer emular lo que consigue realizar la librería Simulink de Matlab.